# What is the best way to solve discrete divide and conquer recurrences?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Note: I have converted my announcement
into a question
and supplied an answer.

What is the best way to solve discrete divide and conquer recurrences?

The "Master Theorem" is one way.

What other ways are available?

Comment: Questions on any SE site should be questions. This would be more appropriate for a personal blog or something of that nature.

Comment: Given the amount of traffic this site sees regarding the Master Theorem and Mellin transform methods, which is considerable, I think a good case can be made for keeping the announcement of this brilliant paper. It may well be that a tag "announcement" would be appropriate for postings of this sort.

Comment: I don't have a blog or a website. I agree that this is not a question, but think that it it appropriate for this site perhaps, as Marko said, as an announcement.

Comment: See my comment.

Comment: I made it a question.

Comment: I made it a question. To bypass the hold, I did it as another question. Oy.